# How do I test my Fluentd config in combination with Elasticsearch?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, fluentd

**Problem:**

I have a complicated setup where I use Elasticsearch and FluentD as part of my logging stack. I would like to add a metric and test the FluentD config for that.

How can I do that?

**Idea:**

Use docker-compose to start an EFK stack. Create a docker container that writes to stdout and simulates logs.

**Problem with my idea:**

The logs written by `mylogger`  never seem to reach Elasticsearch. What am I doing wrong? `mylogger`is a container that simply writes to stdout in a loop and forever using bash.

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  logger:
    image: mylogger
    links:
      - fluentd
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        fluentd-address: localhost:24224
        tag: httpd.access

  fluentd:
    build: ./fluentd
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd/conf:/fluentd/etc
    links:
      - "elasticsearch"
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
      - "24224:24224/udp"

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
    expose:
      - "9200"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"

  kibana:
    image: kibana:7.10.1
    links:
      - "elasticsearch"
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
```

`fluent.conf` File does not contain the changes that I want to make, yet.

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>
<label @FLUENT_LOG>
  <match *.**>
    @type copy
    <store>
      @type elasticsearch
      host elasticsearch
      port 9200
      logstash_format true
      logstash_prefix fluentd
      logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
      include_tag_key true
      type_name access_log
      tag_key @log_name
      flush_interval 1s
    </store>
    <store>
      @type stdout
    </store>
  </match>
</label>
```

Comment: I am just using `echo "test log"` to write my logs. Do I need do write them in a special format?

Comment: Do you see logs on stdout? Is there an index named `fluentd` in ElasticSearch? Do you see any error in fluentd's logs? I'd suggest to test with this minimal config: `<store> @type elasticsearch  host elasticsearch  port 9200  flush_interval 1s</store>`. Format with newlines. Comment out the rest.

Comment: Where are you writing with `echo "test log"`? How is it sending logs to fluentd? The fluentd is listening for logs at port 24224. How is this part connected? Please add this information as well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am trying it with your minimal config. 
I see the logs in stdout. 
There is an index called `fluentd`, but it does not have any data
Fluentd logs: I get a warning `no pattern matched httpd.access`

Comment: I am writing it to stdout. Not to a file or anything. I was hoping that using the fluentd driver was enough.

Comment: Remove/comment start tag `<label @FLUENT_LOG>` and end tag `</label>`. There'll be `source` and `match` enabled. Run your test again.

Comment: I am writing the logs to localhost:24224 now. No luck so far

Comment: How are you writing logs? Command?

Comment: Kibana > Discover > fluentd index shows nothing?

Comment: Kibana > Discover shows me `Ready to try Kibana? First, you need data.`. This is new. There was data before, just not the correct one.

Comment: Right. Try again without `label`.

Comment: In the Kibana logs, I get `["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":8,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.22.0.2:9200"}`. I am not sure if this is just a retry thing, though

Comment: ElasticSearch is running on the same machine?

Comment: Yes. All on the same machine

Comment: I get the connection to Elasticsearch now. But the logs from `mylogger` do not show up

Comment: I am writing the logs via `echo "stuff" | nectar 127.0.0.1 24224`

Comment: Run fluentd with -v flag and test again. Observe fluentd logs. BTW, you can use [`fluent-cat`](https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/command-line-option#fluent-cat) command to send logs to `forward` input  plugin.

Comment: It is working now. I am writing it to stdout in the logger. It works

Comment: Sending logs to ElasticSearch too?

Comment: I get the logs in Kibana, so

Comment: And I can see the indices in elasticsearch via `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/fluentd-20210306/_search?pretty"`

Comment: Good. It's working then.